# Does Spring make the SecurityContext available to the thread executing a Hystrix Command

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I'm running a spring boot app and just starting to integrate Hystrix from spring-cloud-netflix. I'm using @HystrixCommand to wrap a service-to-service call made with a feign client.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "updateThingFallback")
def updateRemoteThing(thingResourceClient: ThingResourceClient, thing: Thing) {
    thingResourceClient.updateThing(thing) // Call using feign client
}
```

This feign client uses the spring security context to add security headers to the request it makes.

The problem I'm having is that when the HystrixCommand is executed it is run in a separate thread from a Hystrix thread pool and when my code tries to access the spring security context it is not available on the new thread.

I'm accessing the spring security context like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

My Question is, does spring provide a way of passing the spring security context (and the application context) to the Hystrix threads that are running the Hystrix commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the `ApplicationContext` in your bean by the normal means.  I can see two ways to pass the authentication object: 1) as a parameter to your method, or 2) run hystrix with [Semaphore isolation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution) rather than on a separate thread.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "updateThingFallback", commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE")
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this works,BUT if I understand `SEMAPHORE` vs `THREAD` correctly, the spot that I"m  having trouble with would have been ideal for THREAD: a network call to a remote service, that at the best of times is not very fast, and too often completely bombs out. So I'm guessing my best option is to rework the code a bit to pass the auth as a param?

Answer (score 13):

Since [Spring Cloud Netflix 1.2.0](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.2.0.RELEASE/#_propagating_the_security_context_or_using_spring_scopes) you can enable sharing of security context with Hystrix using config param:

`hystrix.shareSecurityContext: true`

Comment: btw IDEA will warn you about `Cannot resolve configuration property 'hystrix.shareSecurityContext'`, but it still work well.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this with: [solution example](https://jfconavarrete.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/make-spring-security-context-available-inside-a-hystrix-command/)
But this example is for a spring-boot app, I applie this in a Tomcat 7 the two main changes was:

1. The filter was created in the web.xml.
2. In the init of:"class HystrixRequestContextEnablerFilter" I added: `

   ```
    @Override
           public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
               HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerCommandExecutionHook(new SecurityContextRegistratorCommandHook());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can wrap the Executor used by Hystrix with DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#delegatingsecuritycontextexecutor